# Can I change jobs after 4 months as a Blue Card holder in germany?

Tags: germany, blue-card, foreign-employment

I have received a better job offer than the one I'm currently in and I was wondering if it's possible to change jobs?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible for a Blue card holder to change jobs in Germany freely if you have been there for 2 years.

As you are under the 2 years then you must get permission from your local Ausländerbehörde (ABH) / Immigration office.  You need to make an appointment and take along the contract offer for the new role.

So long as the new role is in the same area and pays the same or more, and everything is OK with the new employer then it should not be an issue.  But you must go through this process to ensure that you will be accepted.

Here are for example details from the Berlin branch.  But you would have to find your local one where you live.
https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/326856/standort/121885/en/